# How to get target of day in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to get the target on where we clicked, when clicking on day in jquery datepicker.

Now I am using onSelect: function (dateText, inst), but this function does not return the target where it was clicked.

I cannot search by class .ui-state-active because I am trying to implement keyboard navigation through multiple months(3) and I am showing days of next/prev month in prev/next month, so we can have two .ui-state-active, and you do not know which one was clicked.

How can I find the clicked element?

Comment: What attribute are you trying to find for the target?

Comment: Here's a generic datepicker fiddle to test on: http://jsfiddle.net/o6eLL05e/1/

Comment: I would like to get target (td/a), where we clicked.

Comment: Here's a jquery forum question about this issue: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-how-to-get-reference-to-the-clicked-a-element-in-rendered-datepicker-calendar